# Explain the output of following?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch;
    if((ch=printf(1234))
        printf("A");
    else
        printf("B");
}
```

Answer is B : 
But i don't know what value is assigned to ch and what happens to printf(1234)

Comment: It should be "Error: Integer where pointer expected" or somesuch, right? If you're not getting about fifty errors from that code, you need to change the warnings settings on your compiler.

Answer (score 3):

From the `printf(3)` man page:

> ```
> Return value
>    Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters
>    printed  (not  including  the  trailing  '\0'  used  to  end  output to
>    strings).
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You could learn to use a debugger and see what value has been assigned to `ch`. Or you could add `printf("%d\n", ch);` at the and of your program and see it that way.

Or you could read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), like [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` returns the number of characters written in the output. However, you have several errors in your code. It should look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ch;
    if(ch=printf("1234"))
        printf("A");
    else
        printf("B");

    return 0;
}
```

In this case ch will be 4, and the output should be 1234A.

UPDATE: modified based on the received comments.

Comment: It still shouldn't look like that. Even if your compiler accepts it, using `void main()` outside of embedded programming ought to be punishable by death or forced viewings of _Transformers 2_.

Comment: @Marius, @Chris -- also `printf` returns an int: a negative value to indicate some error, so the `ch` really should be `int` (or, as it isn't used, simply ommited).

Comment: @chris, that Transformers 2 punishment is way too much for me, so I corrected that obvious void issue

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that your code might not compile on most modern compilers, particularly because of line 5.

But *assuming* your compiler lets you do so, the `printf` will return `0` (this is your `ch`), since nothing was printed. Hence, answer is B.

Answer (score -1):

The signature of printf is

`int printf(const char* restrict fmt, ...)`

and you've passed an integer for the first argument.

The behavior of `printf(1234)` is <strike>undefined</strike> Implementation defined.

> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>  result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation. (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

The behavior is undefined when 1234 happens to point to a valid string that contains format specifiers.

Comment: It would cast the integer to a pointer, which is not undefined per se, just very suspect.

Comment: @Ignacio - I'm fairly certain the compiler is supposed to complain about implicitly casting nonzero integers to pointers.